# Title: How to differentiate sub package and main package name in android?

Tags: java, android, import, package, android-debug

Problem: I'm developing content display app. Now I want to enable GCM push notification app, for that I downloaded a sample project from

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

The sample project is working fine and notification are coming as expected.
Now I copy pasted the following files to my project 
      
 1. manifest file 
      
 2. xml file
      
 3. values file 
      
 4. MainActivity file

I changed the Packagename that I need from the pervious code that I copied but still it is not working. Please guide me  which line i should change the packagename of project , where I should use class packagename and in where i should use the project packagename.

It is giving me error because the package name and sub package name are same.

```
Code: 



           <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <!-- Register Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

being a newbie in android development, I'm not able to figure out which is the main package name in this code.

Any suggestion would be great!. thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving, and where are you seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

We add it like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mymain.package"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Sarthak Mittal is right, but you also need to change your manifest for main activity:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.mymain.package"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


   <activity
    android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```